# replacing strings in files from list in python

Tags: python

So I need to find all files with certain extension in this case `.txt`. Then I must open all these files and change certain string with another string... and here i'm stuck.

here is my code:

```
import os, os.path

find_files=[]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\python programi"):
for f in files:
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
    if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == '.txt':
        find_files.append(fullpath)
for i in find_files:
    file = open(i,'r+')
    contents = file.write()
    replaced_contents = contents.replace('xy', 'djla')
    print i
```

ERROR mesage:

```
line 12, in <module>
    contents = file.write()
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

i know that there is misssing an argument but which argument should I use?
i think it would be better if i change the code from `for i in find files:` down
any advice?

Comment: You cannot write to a file when it's opened for reading (`r+`). If you'd have opened it with `w`, you could `file.write(replaced_contents)`...

Comment: Are you trying to write this back into the file or are you trying to just print it out?

Comment: The error message states that the write function takes 1 argument but 0 has been given.
As per the python documentation , the format for file writing function is 

   

 **f.write(string)** writes the contents of string to the file, returning None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're just trying to print out the changes or if you want to actually rewrite them into the file, in which case you could just do this:

```
for i in find_files:
    replaced_contents = ""
    contents = ""
    with open(i, "r") as file:
        contents = file.read()
        replaced_contents = contents.replace('xy', 'djla')
    with open(i, "w") as file:
        file.write(replaced_contents)
    print i
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to use `file.read()` rather than `file.write()`

Comment: It depends on whether he wants to read it out with the replacement or if he want's to actually replace the file - the `print` statement could just be debugging

Comment: @Scironic Unless there is some nicely idiomatic python way to apply a function to lines in a file, he is going to have to read it in at that point. He may well need to add a write call as well, but that would have to go after the replace call.

Comment: you're right of course - I should have phrased myself better. I was trying to point out that that, whilst this would be an issue, it may not be the main issue which he is interested in. I was getting ahead of myself in that comment.